# Codeigniter: How do I display the value returned by a model function on a view textbox during data entry

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

***This question is based on the following tables.***

```
procedures - id | procedure_name |cost

visits - id | visit_date | patient_id | notes | staff_id

visits_procedures - id | visit_id | procedure_id | quantity

payments - id | visit_id | payment_date | amount | payment_method_id | transanction_id | payment_status_id
```

The payments table records the total amount paid during a visit based on the number of procedures performed. The visits_procedures table tracks the number of procedures performed during a visit. I am trying to populate the amount textbox with the value returned by the `get_visit_amount()` function in the model when creating new payment. However I am getting the error 'Undefined variable: amount'. I would appreciate any ideas on how to make this work. Below are my code snippets.

**Payment model**

```
public function get_visit_amount(){
        $this->db->select_max('id');
        $result= $this->db->get('visits')->row_array();
        $answer = $result['id']; 

        $this->db->select('sum(procedures.cost * visits_procedures.quantity) as amount, visits_procedures.visit_id');
        $this->db->from('procedures');
        $this->db->join('visits_procedures', 'visits_procedures.procedure_id = procedures.id', 'left'); 
        $this->db->where('visits_procedures.visit_id', $answer);       
        $query = $this->db->get()->row_array();
        return $query['amount'];
    }
```

**Payments controller**

```
    public function create() {
            if ($this->input->post('payment_method_id')) {
                $data['visit_id'] = $this->visit->get_latest_id();
                $data['payment_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $data['amount'] = $this->payment->get_visit_amount();
                $data['payment_method_id'] = $this->input->post('payment_method_id');
                $data['transaction_id'] = $this->input->post('transaction_id');
                $data['payment_status_id'] = $this->input->post('payment_status_id');
//set flash data
            $this->session->set_flashdata('display_amount', $amount);
            redirect('/admin/payments/create');

                            $this->payment->insert($data);
                            redirect('/admin/payments', 'refresh');
            }

    .
    .// code to load page
    .

    }
```

**Payments_create view**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="<?=base_url()?>admin/payments/create">
        .
        .//code
        .

    <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Amount</label>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">                                            
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount" value="<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('display_amount'); ?>"/>
                </div>                                            
              </div>
        </div>
        .
        .//code
        .
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [FlashData](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata) to store the information.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');
```

and retrieve it in the new page with

```
$this->session->flashdata('item');
```

Comment: I have tried flashdata as shown in the edited code (controller and view) but it hasn't worked. Could you point out any problems with the code. Does flashdata work for integers? All the examples I have seen use a string yet whatever I want to display is an integer.

Comment: You have two redirects:
`$this->session->set_flashdata('display_amount', $amount);`
`redirect('/admin/payments/create');`

`$this->payment->insert($data);`
`redirect('/admin/payments', 'refresh');`

Which one is the correct redirect? Remember, flashdata is only good for one server call. So if you need to use it on the second redirect, then you need to save it after the first redirect and before the second.